# In Backbone.js , whats the difference between initializing a view by passing a model in the options and passing model object as a paramaeter?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Case 1: Passing model as in options

```
var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    initiliaze:function(){
   }
  });
```

Case 2 : Passing model as a param and setting it using this

```
var View2 = Backbone.View.extend({
   initiliaze:function(model){
     this.model = model
   }
});




var view1 = new View1({model:someModel})
var view2 = new View2(someModel)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same thing, except that in the first case you have less code in your view declaration because Backbone handle setting the model in the view for you (`this.model = model`).

In general Backbone can handle some parameters for you, you can take a look at the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) to have more informations about it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll go through the docs .I've observed when I do it the second way , all the attributes of the model were rendered as attributes of the DOM element too when it renders. Any clue why that happens ?

Comment: @BalaNarayanan That's normal, when you pass an object to the view constructor, Backbone looks for theses attributes ['model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events'] and set it in the view, here's the doc: http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor, so try to avoid the second method because it have side effects